# Compare 2 columns in Excel, removing values from a 3rd and provide results in a 4th, Possibly a nested If Index/Match Formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, multiple-columns

I am trying to find missing SKU's based on the master list in sheets A, B, C - thus;

I have a master SKU list in a column in sheet D.
I want to compare that list against SKU's in a column in sheet A and a column in sheet B.
However I want to ignore any SKU if it is in sheet C.
Provide the final list of results in sheet E.

For simplicity, assume the SKU is in col A for each sheet.

Sounds like a maths problem I know, but I just cannot find the switch that will ignore the values from sheet C.

I was hoping for a formula probably using IF, index and match, but I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some boolean logic (using your `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT` functions) to do this, or you can convert that to straight up math if it's clearer:

Using logical operators:

[image]

Using Math:

[image]

The logical operators are nice since it's clear what the logic is and it probably makes more sense to wrap those up in an `IF()` if you want to change the output from True/False to something else entirely.

Comment: Not sure why, but 100k rows of data on a few sheets and my Excel keeps freezing. Not a slow machine either! Might need VBA for this one

Comment: Thanks again though.

Comment: That's a lot of data to be applying this kind of logic to. Sounds like maybe a database might be appropriate here.